# On en crève - meaning

Tags: sens, pronoms

I have heard the following sentence in the TV series Marseille:

> J'ai besoin d'argent pour reloger les gens qui sont là-bas. On en crève dans ces cités.
> (= People are dying in these ghettos)

Context: A politician who is running for mayor of Marseille is talking about poor people who are having a hard time in the suburbs of the city.

Does the pronoun "en" add any meaning to the sentence? AFAIK there is no idiomatic expression "en crever". Also, it seems to me that the pronoun "en" does not replace neither de + noun/adverb of place nor a noun after an indefinite adjective/number in this sentence.

Comment: En crever is not a verb. I don't understand what you mean exactly.

Comment: @Dimitris I meant there is no expression "en crever" with a different meaning from the base verb, unlike "en vouloir", "en être à", "en être", etc. I have corrected my question.

Comment: I've modified my answer taking into account the update version of the sentence. HTH:-)!

Comment: 1/ Une cité n'est pas un ghetto, à moins d'avoir été transformée en un tel endroit par la force des circonstances (TLFi, Agglomération de pavillons ou d'immeubles à destination particulière) 2/ …"en" replaces neither "de +…" nor …

Comment: @LPH *In the context of this TV series*, "cité" always means "ghetto" or "poor violent neighboorhood". I got the translation from its English subtitles.

Comment: @AlanEvangelista En effet, il existe un courant d'idée qui tend à faire de ce mot un terme péjoratif; je trouve cela dans cette source: https://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cit%C3%A9_(ville)#France. Cependant, il ne s'agit que de connotations et il n'existe pas de sens établi de "cité" en tant que "ghetto". synonymes: http://www.synonymo.fr/synonyme/cit%C3%A9. Je pense que cette redéfinition locale (Marseille, cités ouvrières) va trop loin et devrait être rejetée.

Answer (score 5):

**French**

*Crever* est bien un [verbe](https://www.cnrtl.fr/lexicographie/crever). L'affirmation que *en crever* n'est pas un verbe est incorrecte. (Cette partie traite d'une version précédente de la question.)

En effet, on peut dire 'Crever de faim, de soif,...'.

> Exemple : On peut crever de faim, de soif, des drogues dans ces cités.
> De quoi on peut crever dans ces cités ? De faim, etc.

**En** est un pronom relatif remplaçant ici de faim, etc. Donc,

> On peut *en* crever dans ces cités.

Il va de soi que l'on doit entendre tout le dialogue pour comprendre ce que *en* remplace exactement.

Bonus : [Ngram](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=en%20cr%C3%A8ve%2Cen%20crever%2C%20cr%C3%A8ve%20de%2C%20crever%20de&year_start=1800&year_end=2008&corpus=19&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cen%20cr%C3%A8ve%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cen%20crever%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Ccr%C3%A8ve%20de%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Ccrever%20de%3B%2Cc0)

---

**Brief translation in English**

*Crever* is indeed a verb. The assertion that *en crever* is not a verb is incorrect.] (This part answers to a previous version of the question.)

In fact, one can say

> On peut crever de faim, de soif, des drogues etc. => On peut **en** crever.

**En** is a relative pronoun here replacing de faim, and so on. That is, '*We can die (from these)*'. It goes without saying that one must hear the whole dialogue to understand what exactly *en* replaces.

---

**Update**

La phrase complète mise à jour par l'OP est :

> J'ai besoin d'argent pour reloger les gens qui sont là-bas. On en crève dans ces cités.

Dans ce cas, comme @Greg (merci !) le remarque dans son commentaire, ce n'est pas si clair à quoi le 'en' fait référence ; il peut s'agir soit du manque d'argent, soit du manque de logements décents. En tout cas, cela ne change pas vraiment le sens général.

[What the "en" refers to is not so clear : it can either be the lack of money, or the lack of decent housing. In any case, it does not really change the general meaning.]

Comment: I have updated my question with the previous line in the dialogue: "J'ai besoin d'argent pour reloger les gens qui sont là-bas". Based on your answer, it seems clear now that "en" refers to "d'argent".

Comment: What the "en" refers to is not so clear IMHO: it can either be the lack of money, or the lack of decent housing. In any case, it does not really change the general meaning.

Comment: @Greg Merci Greg pour ton commentaire. J'en ai tenu compte.

Comment: @jlliagre Merci pour l'édit:-)!

Answer (score 3):

It literally means "people die from it in these ghettos" so normally the "it" ("en") part should refer to something that was mentioned earlier in the conversation (such as perhaps drugs, violence, gangs, etc..).